# How to integrate Threading in qt/c++

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I'm currently building an app browser-like. One part is the UI the other is an access to the Android device

I have a class DeviceMngr which is used to instantiate different methods to access to an android device. The instantiate class is gave as argument to the QMainWindow. The QMainWindow will display a QTreewidget and get data from the android device using the MyMtpDevice.

```
DeviceMngr *MyMtpDevice = new DeviceMngr;
error = MyMtpDevice->OpenDevice();
MainUI MyWindow(*MyMtpDevice);
```

How to create a thread in which all call to DeviceMngr such as OpenDevice is done in a separate thread and any other call to a method of this class.

I want a thread for the UI and a thread for the DeviceMngr

Any idea of implementation ? I have try some but seems not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you need. You can do several things, and one of the solutions you should look at is [`boost::thread` and `boost::io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html). It works by creating a thread (in your `DeviceMngr` class) and posting work to it (from other threads):

```
class DeviceMngr
{
public:
    DeviceMngr();
    ~DeviceMngr();
    void OpenDevice();
private:
    void DeviceMngrThread();
    void _OpenDevice() {}

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::thread thread;
    bool run;
};

DeviceMngr::DeviceMngr()
: io_service(),
thread(&DeviceMngr::DeviceMngrThread, this), // create thread
run(true) // start running thread
{
}

DeviceMngr::~DeviceMngr()
{
    run = false; // stop running the thread
    thread.join(); // wait for the thread to finish
    io_service.stop();
}

void DeviceMngr::DeviceMngrThread()
{
    while (run)
    {
        // Process work
        io_service.run();
        // Prepare for more work
        io_service.reset();
    }
}

void DeviceMngr::OpenDevice()
{
    // Post work to do
    io_service.post(boost::bind(&DeviceMngr::_OpenDevice, this));
}
```

Calling `OpenDevice` will simply post work for the `DeviceMngr` thread to handle. This simple example should help you get started and to learn how threads work. I would suggest starting with small examples so you can learn how it all works together (seeing as though calls to `OpenDevice` will not be synchronous. If you require synchronisation, you may need to look towards [boost synchronisation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html)

Comment: That mean that all the open device processing should be declared in the _OpenDevice.